# Auto increment name and ID in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, variables, loops, include

Ok so I have a php script that takes a variable, explodes it by lines, and then counts the lines. If there are more than three lines, the variable is split and everything beyond the three lines is put into an expandable javascript box. This entire script is in a loop because I have more than one variable that gets processed for this line number check.

The script for the expandable javascript area I found online because I am awful at javascript so I am not sure how to change this.

SO:

1. because this script is in a loop it is running many different times for different variables. So i need the "a1" to be a variable that increases by one every time this script runs. otherwise, the "Expand" button expands ALL boxes if I run more than one variable becasue they are all named the same. This would be a piece of cake in php but I am lost in javascript.
2. Also, more of a side note, but does anyone know how I can better incorporate this javascript in my php without constant ending and starting my php?

Here is the portion of my php with the javascript.

```
     if ($numberlines > 3) 
            {

            ?>

            <div onClick="openClose('a1')"style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer"><b>Expand</b></div>
            <div id="a1" class="texter">

                <?php

                foreach ($data as $final) 
                    {
                        echo $final."";
                    }

                ?>

            <br /><br />
            </div>


            <?php

            }

                            ?>
```

Comment: `onClick` might give you problems. Try `onclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a loop already, you should be able to use an auto-incrementing integer to handle the updated naming.

For example:

```
 $count = 0;
 while(keepGoing)
 {
     if ($numberlines > 3) 
     {
         $count++;
 ?>

 <div onClick="openClose('a<?=$count?>')"style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer"><b>Expand</b></div>
 <div id="a<?=$count?>" class="texter">

 <?php
         foreach ($data as $final) 
         {
             echo $final."";
         }
 ?>

        <br /><br />
        </div>

 <?php
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to you first question, as far as I know it's no possible to carry a variable across script executions without storing the value in a file or passing it as a URL parameter. If I were you I would rewrite your script to only be executed once, and wrap your code in a function that takes the input variable as an argument, then call it for each variable, that way you can easily have the a1 variable stored across your different calls for each variable.

Hope that helps